# Outlook Com Exception

Tags: c#, iis, com, outlook

I have a c# .net app that opens an instance of outlook and populates the bcc section of the email.  When I run .Net locally, it works fine.  If I go to the server and open IIS and browse to the app, it works fine.

When I browse to the app in Internet Explorer, it won't open outlook and populate the bcc.

Here is my code to open the instance of outlook.

```
                Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApplication.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem); 
                mailItem.BCC = emailList;
                mailItem.Display(true);
```

Here is the warning from the event viewer in the server manager:

```
    Exception information: 
Exception type: COMException 
Exception message: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

What am I missing or what do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running on the server, not the client. You need to use a client-side script for that - assuming your script has the right to actually create local COM objects and the user is using IE (no other browsers support COM obejcts).

Secondly, Outlook, just like any other Office app, cannot be used in a service (such as IIS).

Comment: I tried to use an a href with mailto:, but that had a character limit.  The app needs to handle emailing numerous people, which is why I had to find another way to do this.